# How to handle navigation properties with newsequentialid primary keys?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I have a parent/child/grandchild relationship using sequentialguid keys:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Parent]
(
    [parentid] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID(),
    [data] VARCHAR(32),
    CONSTRAINT [PK_parent] PRIMARY KEY ([parentid])
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Child]
(
    [childid] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID(),
    [parentid] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    [data] VARCHAR(32)
    CONSTRAINT [PK_child] PRIMARY KEY ([childid]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_parent_child] FOREIGN KEY ([parentid])
        REFERENCES [dbo].[Parent] ([parentid])
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[grandchild]
(
    [grandchildid] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID(),
    [childid] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    [data] VARCHAR(32)
    CONSTRAINT [PK_grandchild] PRIMARY KEY ([grandchildid]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_child_grandchild] FOREIGN KEY ([childid])
        REFERENCES [dbo].[child] ([childid])
)
```

And I have an Entity Framework transaction:

```
public void SaveChild(Child aChild)
{
    using (var db = new MyDbContext())
    {
        db.childs.Add(aChild);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

When I call this method with a new Child, a new Child record is created, with a new childid.

And a new Parent record is created, with a new parentid.

But here's the thing. Sometimes I'm adding a new child with a new parent, and sometimes I'm adding a new child with an existing parent. And in all cases, I want to add new grandchildren.

Entity Framework, on an Add() with DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID(), seems to ignore any current value of the GUIDs and always creates a new one.

And that results in duplicate parent records.

And I can't have that.

What is a clean way of getting an Add() of the child record to recognize that the parent record already exists, and to update the fields of the existing record, rather than to create a new one?

Answer (score 0):

It should work as long as you've told EF that the PK on each table is an Identity column and you ensure that when associating an existing entity, that the DB Context is tracking that entity. (I.e. avoid passing entity references around beyond the scope of the DbContext that read them)

For instance: For the PK declarations using attribute notation in your entities:

```
public class Parent
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid ParentId { get; set; }
}
```

This ensures that EF will treat the IDs are identity / DB generated values.

The second thing that trips people up especially with web applications is passing entities around and assuming that a request with a new DbContext will know whether it's dealing with an existing entity or a new one.

For instance in one method we read and return a parent...

```
using (var context = new AppDbContext())
{
    return context.Parents.Single(x => x.ParentId == parentId);
}
```

... then later when we wanted to create a new child associated with the parent, the client code created a child object, associated the existing Parent that we earlier read, and passed it back to the server:

```
public void CreateChild(Child child)
{
    using(var context = new AppDbContext())
    {
        context.Children.Add(child);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
    // Where child.Parent == existing Parent, but DbContext inserts a new Parent.
}
```

The same thing would happen here:

```
Parent parent = null;
using (var context1 = new AppDbContext())
{
    parent = context1.Parents.Single(x => x.ParentId == parentId);
}

using (var context2 = new AppDbContext())
{
    Child newChild = new Child
    {   
        Parent = parent,
        Name = "Sven"
    }
    context2.Children.Add(newChild);
    context2.SaveChanges();
}
```

`newChild.Parent` was a parent that was associated with `context1`. As far as `context2` is concerned it is a new, untracked entity.

You can solve this issue in 2 ways:

A) Attach the entities

```
Parent parent = null;
using (var context1 = new AppDbContext())
{
    parent = context1.Parents.Single(x => x.ParentId == parentId);
}

using (var context2 = new AppDbContext())
{
    context2.Parents.Attach(parent);
    Child newChild = new Child
    {   
        Parent = parent,
        Name = "Sven"
    }
    context2.Children.Add(newChild);
    context2.SaveChanges();
}
```

Now `context2` is tracking `parent` and will treat it as an existing entity. The catch here is that `Attach` can fail if the DbContext instance is already tracking an entity with that ID. In the above example that won't happen because we scoped the DbContext with a `using` block, but if you are using Dependency Injection and scoping a DbContext to the request this could happen if some condition caused that Parent to be loaded prior to this code being called. Dealing with detaching/reattaching entities can be a bit of a pain. To be safe you should check if the DbContext is tracking the entity and replace those references...

```
using (var context2 = new AppDbContext())
{
    var trackedParent = context2.Parents.Local.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ParentId == parent.ParentId);
    if (trackedParent == null)    
        context2.Parents.Attach(parent);
    else
        parent = trackedParent;

    Child newChild = new Child
    {   
        Parent = parent,
        Name = "Sven"
    }
    context2.Children.Add(newChild);
    context2.SaveChanges();
}
```

With more complex entity graphs (parents, grandchildren, and various references to other entities, etc.) each and every reference needs to be tracked. Missing one can result in an intermittent appearing error if some condition leads to an existing entity reference slipping through.

B) Don't pass entities, always deal with IDs and let the DbContext fetch the entities. Rather than passing entities around, pass DTOs and FKs. So when we create our Child in the client, we pass a CreateChildViewModel which contains a ParentId to associate with rather than a Parent entity. View Models/DTOs can help make the payload size between client and server more compact as well.

```
public void CreateChild(CreateChildViewModel childVM)
{
    using(var context = new AppDbContext())
    {
        var parent = context.Parents.Single(x => x.ParentId == childVM.ParentId);
        var child = new Child
        {
            Parent = parent;
            Name = childVM.Name;
            // ...
        };
        context.Children.Add(child);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

In cases where a DbContext scoped to the request is already tracking an entity reference it will return that reference when requested or look it up in the DB. The decision to pass entities around can be tempting to avoid calls to the DB, however this leads to more complexity in the logic to check and replace references if entities are already being tracked, (or annoying, breaking bugs to track down) and can lead to data tampering or stale data overwrites if entities are attached and set to Modified or use the DbContext `Update` method. Fetching entities from the DbContext by PK is extremely fast.